# How do you reconcile the difference between these two common integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Can someone please reconcile the difference between the two common integrals below? They are almost identical except what's inside the natural log function. The denominator signs are switched depending on whether it's the variable x or u. I understand u represents a function where as x represents a variable but I'm not sure how it affects the outcome within the natural log function. Please explain

[Two similar common integrals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9V2Hb.png)

Comment: You've forgotten the $||$ outside the fraction.

Comment: There is no difference, $|p|=|-p|$

Comment: Oh man, I feel foolish now. Thanks guys!